# What is the unit of measurement for cookie size in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

attached is the screenshot of chrome developer tools. Here the cookie size is displayed at 508 and 51. There is no mention for unit of measurement for this size. **how do we know which it is- Bytes, KB or MB.**

[image: dev tools]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Source: [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/#:%7E:text=Size.%20The%20cookie%27s%20size%2C%20in%20bytes.)

> Size. The cookie's size, in bytes.